# Can I know what does this specific line of code means and how do i put it in a for loop in Python

Tags: python

> I want to know what does this specific line means ?
> **vowels = [i for i in string if i in m]**

*The main code is : *

```
  def count_vowel(string):
    m = "AaEeIiOoUu"
    vowels = [i for i in string if i in m]
    if len(vowels) == 0:
        print("No vowels in the name")
    else:
        print(vowels)
        print("count:", len(vowels))

string = (input("enter anything to find amount of vowels in it :"))
count_vowel(string)
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It builds a new list where each item takes on each of the characters in the string stored in the variable `string`, but a value is only produced if that character is also found in the string `m`.

---

The general structure for a list comprehension is:

`resultingList = [operateOnIteratorsToProduceResult(i1, i2) for i1, i2 in iterable if condition] # lists are iterables`

This can be seen as a conditional mapping, where we map the iterator(s) to a corresponding result if and only if the condition evaluates to `True` (otherwise no value is produced, and we continue iterating).

A special case (the one in your example), is where you simply produce the iterator. In that case, you are simply filtering the iterable on the condition:

`resultingList = [i for i in iterable if condition]`

There is also a full mapping like:

`resultingList = [operateOnIteratorsToProduceResult(i1, i2) for i1, i2 in iterable if condition else alternativeResult]`

where `operateOnIteratorsToProduceResult(i1, i2)` is produced as that element in the resulting list if the condition evaluates to `True`, otherwise `alternativeResult` is produced.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to understand list comprehension is by separating out the parts.

It is equivalent to:

```py
vowels = []
for i in string:
    if i in m:
        vowels.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which iterates through the string and filters out all the values that are in the `m` string, and converts back into a string.

From the documentation:

> A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression followed by a `for` clause, then zero or more `for` or `if` clauses. The result will be a new list resulting from evaluating the expression in the context of the `for` and `if` clauses which follow it.